# Angular help: Springboot backend

Tags: angular, observable, subscribe

I am working on a poc for Angular with Springboot backend. Following code is interacting with EmployeeService. This area of code is not working, control is not going into alert("getEmployees2". Any idea what is going on here?

**employee-list.component.ts**

```
private getEmployees() {
    //alert("getEmployees " + this.employees); 
    this.employeeService.getEmployeesList().subscribe(data => {
      alert("getEmployees2" + this.employees.length);
      this.employees = data;
    });
}
```

**employee.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Employee } from './employee';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {
  
  private baseURL = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employees";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient ) { }

  getEmployeesList(): Observable<Employee[]> {
     alert(`${this.baseURL}`);
     return this.httpClient.get<Employee[]>(`${this.baseURL}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: No chance to tell, you need to provide more information. What das the EmployeeService and its getPloyeesList() method look like?

Comment: Why would you alert `this.employees` before setting it? Check your browser console for errors.

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employees. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Comment: First, you need to get the data from the service (whatever that), then assign it. For a simple fix, you need to swap the two lines in the subscribe method. Second, if you are not able to get the data from the service due to whatever reason, you need to fix it too. 
Always use console.log(' your print statement here') instead of alert(''), it is handier.

Comment: Hussain, if your own answer solved the problem, you should accept it, for the benefit of others with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling Websecurity resolved the issue:

```
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        httpSecurity.cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        
        
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How to solve this problem:

```
private getEmployees() {
    //alert("getEmployees " + this.employees); 
    this.employeeService.getEmployeesList().subscribe(data => {
      this.employees = data; 
      alert("getEmployees2" + this.employees.length); //move this alert line down like this would solve the problem 
    });
}
```

also in your Springboot backend under the annotation:

```
@RestController
```

add:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I do not know if you saw, but the Question's original author (OP) answer it himself, saying that it was solved after WebSecurity enabling. Thus, the chances for your answer to be accepted or correct, in this case, are greatly reduced; in the same way the chances of your answer being upvoted also decrease.